# Control not visible even ctrl.Visible = true

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I use following code (C#, Net4) to update the visibility of a label (its initially not visible):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    lbNumberImages.Visible = true;
                }));
            }).
        ContinueWith
            ((task) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        task.Wait();
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ae)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ae.InnerException.Message);
                        }));
                    }
                });
```

If the form is visible the label gets visible. If the form is not visible the label remains hidden even when the form gets visible. What is wrong with this code?

The code is called - if I set a breakpoint on the line 'lbNumberImages.Visible = true;' the debugger stops.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, or what?

Comment: Well, I never use WinForms, but does it happen to have an `UpdateLayout()` method on the UI? Maybe that's what you could use. Maybe the UI doesn't get refreshed until the Task completes.

Comment: Update: All changes are not happen. Even if I only change the text of the label (the label is visible all the time) the text of the label does not change when the parent control (a UserControl) is not visible!?!?

Comment: It ought to be possible to put together a short yet complete program that illustrates the behaviour. If you did that then we could give you the answer easily with little effort on our part. And no guess work.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh. I found the error. Somewhere in an other thread I had a label.Text = ""; Sorry, my mistake.